# Bootstrap : accordian not collpased in beginning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am using following code to have accordian , problem is that its not collapsed in beginning , would you please help me how will it be collapsed until clicked

i got code from [codepen](https://codepen.io/Sp00ky/pen/zBZZvq)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".toggle-accordion").on("click", function() {
            var accordionId = $(this).attr("accordion-id"),
            numPanelOpen = $(accordionId + ' .collapse.in').length; 
            $(this).toggleClass("active"); 

        })  
    });
</script>


<style>
    .panel-body{
        padding:10px;
        font-size:15px;
    }
    input[type="checkbox"] {
        margin-right: 12px !important;
    }
    .col-sm-4{
        margin-bottom:40px;
    }
    .leftindent{
        margin-left:30px;
    }
    .panel-default>.panel-heading {
        color: #333;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-color: #e4e5e7;
        padding: 0;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }

    .panel-default>.panel-heading a {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 15px;
    }

    .panel-default>.panel-heading a:after {
        content: "";
        position: relative;
        top: 1px;
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        float: right;
        transition: transform .25s linear;
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .25s linear;
    }

    .panel-default>.panel-heading a[aria-expanded="true"] {
        background-color: #eee;
    }

    .panel-default>.panel-heading a[aria-expanded="true"]:after {
        content: "\2212";
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }

    .panel-default>.panel-heading a[aria-expanded="false"]:after {
        content: "\002b";
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }

    .accordion-option {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        clear: both;
        margin: 15px 0;
    }

    .accordion-option .title {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        float: left;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .accordion-option .toggle-accordion {
        float: right;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #6a6c6f;
    }

    .accordion-option .toggle-accordion:before {
        content: "Expand All";
    }

    .accordion-option .toggle-accordion.active:before {
        content: "Collapse All";
    }

</style>
```

and following is the html code .

```
   <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
     <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
         <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#cookiesandbiscotti" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                            4 Cookies &amp; Biscotti
                                        </a>
                                    </h4>
                                </div>
     <div id="cookiesandbiscotti" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
        <div class="panel-body">
        <?php foreach($mincookines as $value):?>
           <div class="form-group"><input type="checkbox"><?= $value;?></div>
         <?php endforeach;?>
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Once see this [link](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/3kB4m)

Answer (score 2):

I have the solution for you. You need to remove `in` class from `class="panel-collapse collapse in"` so that it can be in its normal state. And make `aria-expanded="true"` to `false` . It will work for you. Here you can see the updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/anmol1591/pen/rzvwLz)

Code

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="accordion-option">
    <h3 class="title">Lorem Ipsum</h3>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="toggle-accordion active" accordion-id="#accordion"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please remove `in` class form div id `cookiesandbiscotti`.

Answer (score 1):

remove class 'in', or add too first item if you want that first item was open

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `in` class from `class="panel-collapse collapse in"` and you are good to go.